# Not able to replace apostrophe value from text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file. I am reading all data from that text file. I have given code like this for removing all apostrophe and column, and double quotes, and comma.

```
 sr = New StreamReader(Filename)


        temp_data = sr.ReadLine

        While Not temp_data = Nothing
            'While sr.Peek() >= 0
            sTemp = Split(temp_data, "|", -1)

            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To sTemp.Length - 1
                Replace(sTemp(i), ",", "")
                Replace(sTemp(i), "'", "")
                Replace(sTemp(i), """", "")

            Next
```

Then I am assigning value like this:

```
  POnum = Trim(sTemp(0))
                POline = Trim(sTemp(1))
                PORelnum = Trim(sTemp(2))
```

But still I am getting value with apostrophe. What is wrong with my code.

Comment: `Replace` is a function, not a sub.

Comment: what is the use of checking each character in stemp ?? you can simply replace using `sTemp.Replace("'", "")`

Comment: @akhilkumar It's checking each string of the array of strings which resulted from splitting on "|".

Comment: stemp is a string no,so just try using the above mentioned method to replace.

Comment: @akhilkumar - `sTemp` is an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the string that has the replaced text. Consequently it is lost. You should save it back in `sTemp(i)`

```
        For i = 0 To sTemp.Length - 1
            sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), ",", "")
            sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), "'", "")
            sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), """", "")

        Next
```

However I think a better way would be to remove these characters before splitting so that there is no need to loop and remove from the array.

```
    While Not temp_data = Nothing
        temp_data = temp_data.Replace( ",", "").Replace( "'", "").Replace("""", "")
        sTemp = Split(temp_data, "|", -1)

        '-- no need to loop and replace now
```

This saves a lot of unnecessary code, isn't it?

Comment: dear sir..in my text 2000 records..so if i write your second code that will replace ?

Comment: Both ways will work, but the second way is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

you have been trying to replace an array value within its scope.But it is easier to replace that value when it is assigned to a string and then it is assigned.here the code

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim temp_data As String
Dim clean As String = String.Empty
While Not sr.EndOfStream
    temp_data = reader.ReadLine()
    Dim sTemp = temp_data .Split("|")                 

    For Each j As String In sTemp 
        clean = j
        clean = clean.Replace("'", "").Replace("""", "").Replace(",", "")            
        sTemp(i) = clean
        i += 1
    Next
End While
```

this will help you..